# Linux - Command a2ps For PDF File

Tags: linux, command-line

it is possible to print a PDF file with the a2ps command? If someone could give me an example set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [a2ps](https://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/) and [enscript](http://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/) commands are both intended to write PostScript files (which is the meaning of the 'ps' letters in a2ps). If you are happy with the output of a2ps and want to convert it to PDF format, you have to convert the Postscript output itself to PDF with:

```
ps2pdf output.ps
```

which will create a file called *output.pdf*. If you want to focus rather on the idea of directly create PDF documents, there are some more recent alternatives.

I wrote myself a Python program called txt2pdf; you may find it [here](https://github.com/baruchel/txt2pdf). Have also a look at tools like [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), [gimli](https://github.com/walle/gimli), [rst2pdf](https://code.google.com/p/rst2pdf/) or [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) but you may have to change slightly your workflow.

Answer (score 1):

In certain customized installations, a2ps may offer a -P pdf flag, but this is not standard, e.g. Debian Linux does not come with such a configuration.

Answer (score 1):

A *bit* late, but you can generate a PDF in one command using pipes like so.

```
a2ps some_file.py -o- | ps2pdf - out.pdf
```

The `-o-` option tells `a2ps` to write the result to STDOUT;
the `-` option tells `ps2pdf` to read from STDIN.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a [u2ps](https://sourceforge.net/projects/u2ps.berlios/) utility requiring Perl and GhostScript that may do as well.